# Tasklist | sort /+ number reference

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a reference which lists the different number codes that be used with the Tasklist | sort /+ command in Windows command line?

The only one I know of is Tasklist | sort /+68

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Those numbers aren't codes. This is simply how you tell `sort` which character in each line to start the comparisons at – `/+68` means sort by the column starting at character #68 from the left.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I will have to guess at the other character numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Run tasklist > c:\temp\task.txt
Use notepad++ or pspad to open the txt file.
Arrow over to the beginning of the line you want to sort by.
check the Col: on your text editor (bottom on notepad++) for the character number.
Run tasklist | sort /+(column number found in text editor).